# Continuous build framework for java+python+ruby?

Tags: java, python, ruby, continuous-integration

Our technology set includes java, python, and ruby code (no, we're not google ;-) ).

Recommendations on good CI framework to use?  Hudson?  Other?

dwh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/). It's written in Java so it runs on most platforms, has a very pleasant web-interface and excellent usability, and plugins for [Python](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Python+Plugin) and [Ruby](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Ruby+Plugin) as well as supporting shell scripts out of the box. It integrates well with SCM - for example, it can be triggered by checking in changes to a repository. It has lots of useful [plugins](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Plugins).

Comment: Re: Hudson plugins, even if the existing Python/Ruby plugins don't work the way you want, you can always write one.  The plugin API is really easy to work with from what I remember.  The last company I was at actually had an in-house developed plugin for compiling .Net code with Nant.  One of our junior developers wrote it over the course of a couple evenings and said the docs were pretty good.

Comment: Hudson's at the top of our list.  Good to hear the endorsement.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/).  It's based on ANT, so it's easy to write your build xml files for any language that you want...  It also has builder support for Rake and a bunch of others (NANT, Maven, Phing and XCode, not to mention anything that can be run from the command line), so you should be good to go.